# apache camel rest Patch

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

my team is looking at using camel for our project, we have a api management team that enforces some standards on us one of this is the use of Patch. We have to support patch but from what I've seen camel (v2.15) doesn't support Patch as an rest api method.

for example I can't do this as I would with POST:
rest("/application").patch().type(Application.class).outType(ApplicationResponse.class).to(CREATE_APPLICATION_ENDPOINT);

is there a way to enable patch? am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What about the `HTTP4` component you can include in your project?

[HTTP4 Component, which supports routing via HTTP verbs, including PATCH](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html)